# Should I put client and server in the same jar

Tags: maven, architecture, client, server

While creating a new web application using [spring-boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), I wondered about a philosophical question: is the best practice to have only one maven module (and so one jar) for both server-side app and static web content of the client (to generate another jar, maybe?), or is it better to have one maven module for server and another one for client-side?

In other words, is it better to have this maven architecture:

```
MyProject-parent
    - MyProject
```

or this one ?

```
MyProject-parent
    - MyProject-server
    - MyProject-html-client
    - MyProject-mobile-client
    - ...
```

As I would like to have a browser client and a mobile one, I would be tempted to say it's a good idea to have separate modules. However, using Spring-boot, it's possible to generate a fat jar, i.e. a jar containing all the other ones. As a consequence, the recommended architecture is, I suppose, only one maven module.

So is there a "better" solution? If yes, can you give me arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the multi module approach for the following reasons:

- The project is gonna grow and it gets better organized this way,
  which means it would be easier to maintain in future and if you break
  the modules properly in the beginning, you are not gonna have to lose
  time to refactor and split it into different modules later.
- It's better "layered”
- It's better for bug fix or make new functionalities, since you can
  focus on only one module and run the test only for that one.
- As you are using Maven, it helps a lot with the dependencies, you can
  build it all with one single maven command and it takes care of the
  build order. So I can't see any advantage of using single module for
  your case.
- You might need to release MyProject-mobile-client without releasing
  MyProject-html-client any time in future in case you are planning to
  use maven release.

Comment: It makes sense. I was just wondering about 2 things: 1) Why does not spring-boot encourage using such an approach (as you can do a fat jar that should be hard to build with multi-modules, I suppose). 2) If I decide to move to a traditional war/ear architecture, would I not encounter difficulties as the HTML client must be packaged within the war?